# How to find company GUID in twinfield?

Tags: twinfield

```
<soap:Header>
<Header xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/">
  <SessionID>string</SessionID>
  <AccessToken>string</AccessToken>
  <CompanyCode>string</CompanyCode>
  <CompanyId>guid</CompanyId>
</Header>
</soap:Header>
```

The twinfield header soap call requires CompanyId guid which is a 32 character string separated by 4 dashes(-). How to find the guid?

Answer (score 0):

The url you have to use is this:
[https://login.twinfield.com/auth/authentication/connect/accesstokenvalidation?token={{Accescode}}](https://login.twinfield.com/auth/authentication/connect/accesstokenvalidation?token=%7B%7BAccescode%7D%7D)

Assuming you know the access code, this will give you the results, including the organisationId.
This seems what you will need.

If you need you can find the how to make the accesscode [here](https://accounting.twinfield.com/webservices/documentation/#/ApiReference/Authentication/OpenIdConnect)